# How to efficiently find all element combination including a certain element in the list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have the following list :

```
alist={{5, 6, 7}, {7, 6, 8}, {5, 7, 25}, {7, 8, 26}, {7, 26, 25}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 12, 6}, {6, 12, 13}, {6, 13, 8}}
```

I want to find all element combinations with size 2 including number 7.

The desired outcome is: `{{5,7},{6,7},{7,8},{7,25},{7,26}}`.

I initially tried to solve using permutation, but permutation will keep all combinations with size 2 no matter number 7 in it or not.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select[MemberQ[7]][
 DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ Flatten[#, 1] &@(Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
      alist))]
```

> {{5, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {7, 25}, {7, 26}}

Answer (score 6):

another possibility (8 more left to go)

```
Cases[alist, {___, 7, ___}]
Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ %, 1]
Union@Cases[%, x_ /; Not[FreeQ[x, 7]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I assumed `{6,7}` and `{7,6}` are different. That is why I kept both. It will be easy to filter one of these out if needed.

**Update for comment**

To handle `{6,7}` and `{7,6}` being different, simply sort before using Union. Like this

```
Cases[alist, {___, 7, ___}]
Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ %, 1]
Sort[#] & /@ Cases[%, x_ /; Not[FreeQ[x, 7]]]
Union[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort /@ Select[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ alist, 1], 
   MemberQ[#, 7] &]]
```

You can use `Union` instead of `DeleteDuplicates`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Orderless` to “sort” list.

```
SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
{{5, 6, 7}, {7, 6, 8}, {5, 7, 25}, {7, 8, 26}, {7, 26, 25}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 12, 6}, {6, 12, 13}, {6, 13, 8}} //
Select[MemberQ[7]] //
Map[Subsets[#, {2}]&] //
Flatten[#, 1]& //
f @@@ # & //
DeleteDuplicates //
List @@@ # & //
Select[MemberQ[7]]
```

> {{5, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {7, 25}, {7, 26}}